# After insert trigger can do an update?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-5.5

I'm new to the creation of triggers but I need it since I'm using a persistent storage for some IDs.

I have the table `RECEIPT` with a column `RECEIPT_ID`

and the table `CONFIG_DB` with columns and values:

```
NAME               VALUE
---------------    -----   
NEXT_RECEIPT_ID      1
```

and I created this trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER UPDATE_RECEPCION_ID

AFTER INSERT ON RECEIPT

FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN

UPDATE CONFIG_DB SET VALUE=VALUE+1;

END    
;
```

I don't know if this is OK... all I want its that after I insert a new `RECEIPT_ID` the `VALUE` in `CONFIG_DB` increases by 1. Thank you very much.

EDIT: I work in Mysql Workbench 5.2.40 with Mysql Server 5.5.25

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... things like triggers are highly vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: It seems you are using that "CONFIG_DB" table to generate unique numbers. Don't. Use an auto_increment instead.

Comment: Im using CONFIG_DB as a persistent storage because the ID i generate for RECEIPT_ID its REC-"YEAR""MONTH"0000

Comment: The number of 4 digits its the one i need to increase so i have to storage it in the DB the rest of data of the ID like YEAR or MONTH its taken from the DateChooser thats is in the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following query to create trigger

```
delimiter |
CREATE
    TRIGGER `UPDATE_RECEPCION_ID` 
     AFTER INSERT ON `RECEIPT`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     UPDATE CONFIG_DB SET VALUE=VALUE+1 
     WHERE  NAME='NEXT_RECEIPT_ID';
    END;
    |
```

Comment: Thats exactly how i ended up it doing it xD Thanks